# How to confirm dropbox api auth and return back to my page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox-api

I am trying to integrate dropbox api into my web application. So i instated dropnet from github and created App key and App secrete. My code is below

```
//Upload To dropbox

DropNetClient _client = new DropNetClient("myappkey", "myappSecret");

_client.GetToken();

var url = _client.BuildAuthorizeUrl();

_client.GetTokenAndBuildUrl(Server.MapPath("/User/Encrypt.aspx"));

var accessToken = _client.GetAccessToken();
var filebytes = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Encrypted Files/" + txtFile.FileName));
byte[] content = _client.GetFileContentFromFS(filebytes);
var result = _client.UploadFile("/Encrypted Files/", txtFile.FileName, content);

 Response.Write("<script>alert('File Encrypted and Uploaded to Cloud..!');

</script>");
```

But my problem is when execution reach at `var url = _client.BuildAuthorizeUrl();`, I want to copy the url and manually open a new tab in browser past url and confirm auth.
and allow to execute remaining code. How to overcome this. is there any option to handle auth confirmation in code itself or to redirect the auth confirmation page and afterconfirmation  i wanto go back to my code and execute remining?
now i am handling by manually. i want to do everything automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be entirely automated. The user needs to explicitly and manually authorize the app to access their account. This is done the via the OAuth flow.

Note that this only needs to be done once per user though. Afterwards, your app can store and re-use the resulting access token (unless the user or apps explicitly revokes the token of course, at which point the app can ask the user to re-authorize it).

There's an OAuth guide here that may be helpful:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide

Comment: Is it possible to redirect back to my application page after allow  auth? @Greg

Comment: Yes, if you're using OAuth 1, using the `oauth_callback` parameter: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#authorize For OAuth 2, using the `redirect_uri` parameter: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-authorize